# Empty view is added to linear layout

Tags: android, view, android-linearlayout, layout-inflater

I want to inflate a given `layout`, add text to the `textviews` inside it and then add this view to a `LinearLayout` dynamically and this `view` is to be added multiple times in the `linearLayout`.
The view to be inflated is this :-

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="10dp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:layout_weight="1">
       <TextView
           android:textSize="13sp"
           android:id="@+id/tv1"

           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:layout_weight="3">
        <TextView

            android:id="@+id/tv2"
            android:textSize="13sp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:layout_weight="3">
        <TextView
            android:textSize="13sp"
            android:id="@+id/tv3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <TextView
            android:textSize="13sp"
            android:id="@+id/tv4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    </LinearLayout>
```

The `LinearLayout` inside which it has to be added is this :-

```
    <LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/pass_info"
    android:layout_below="@+id/booking_title"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">


</LinearLayout>
```

The final view should be like this :-

```
1 mark 50%
2 sam  30%
3 ava  45%
```

The `view` is added dynamically one below the other. The code which I used was this :-

```
 for(int i = 0; i <  getStudentCount(); i++){
        LayoutInflater vi=(LayoutInflater)getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        LinearLayout insertPoint=(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.pass_info);
        View v=vi.inflate(R.layout.pass_item,insertPoint,false);

        TextView textView1=(TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.tv1);
        TextView textView2=(TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.tv2);
        TextView textView3=(TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.tv3);
        TextView textView4=(TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.tv4);

        textView1.setText(getRollNum(i));
        // likewise for other textviews
        insertPoint.addView(v);
        }
```

The `views` are added but it shows nothing, the `textviews` are blank. What is the probable cause?

Comment: instead of this you can use List/Recycler with a TextView.

Comment: Yes I can, but some UI limitations is reason for not choosing that widget. This should also work.

Comment: can you write one please, may be I'm missing some thing.

Comment: This looks fine. Is `getRollNum(i)` returning a valid string?

Comment: The layout contains a linear layout in the upper part with some static views and in the lower half I need to have a listview. I want the layout such that the whole page is scrolled along with the listview. But the only the listview is getting scrolled and that too in a very small region which is making the UI look bad.

Comment: @Shaishav yes the string is set. That is checked.

Answer (score 1):

**Problems in your code**

Your code has several issues regarding layout inflating and view binding. What you want to achieve is different from what your code implements.

**Steps to achieve what you desire**

What you want to do is:

- Create a class that inflates the layout with tv1, tv2... Let us say this class is called TextsClass. You can learn more about it [here](https://developer.android.com/training/custom-views/index.html). This is where you will inflate the layout with the textviws.
- Then, inside this class, you do findViewById to tv1, tv2 and so on (`tv1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv1);` to bind them to the parent layout)
- Create methods to set the text in these TextViews, such as 
  `public TextView setTv1Text(String text) tv1.setText(text);`
- Then, in the for loop, you have to instance new TextClass objects. After you instance them, you get each of the TextViews and set their texts, such as:

  ```
  TextsClass textsClass = new TextsClass(getContext());
  textsClass.setTv1Text(getRollNum(i));
  //Do it with the other textviews
  insertPoint.add(textsClass);
  ```

**Summary about your code**

- You are inflating linearLayouts several times (the insertPoint one) inside the for loop and you only need to do that once (before the for loop)
- You are inflating one layout (insertPoint) and trying to bind views from ANOTHER layout into it (tv1, tv2...)
- You are binding views several times inside the loop, which is unnecessary (if not problematic)
- You are trying to use the same textviews to put into the insertPoint layout and you can't do that. You can't use layout.add(child) with repeated children, they all must be different (that's why you must always instance new children in the for loop, in our example, the TextsClass).

Try to follow the link from google to create custom views, that's the way to go and, then, follow the steps I specified here to achieve what you want.

Let me know if my answer helped you, cheers.

Answer (score 0):

```
    Linearlayout  frameLayout = (LinearLayout ) view.findViewById(R.id.frm);
    LayoutInflater inflatr = (LayoutInflater) Context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View  menuLayout = inflatr.inflate(R.layout.n_demoview, frameLayout, true);
```

This Will be work for me
I hope this will work for you!!